# wandora ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: scripts, launcher, mate

Wandora http://www.wandora.org/wiki/Download ,followed by an appropriate tar unpacking of the file from the Download URL, has a .sh file for execution under Linux.  Within MATE, from a MATE terminal, the file executes.  Using MATE Caja, and pointing and clicking on the sh file, then Run in Terminal, wandora runs.  However, when I Create Launcher on the desktop, using Application in Terminal from the pull down menu therein, and using the same sh file, a terminal appears for a moment, closes, and wandora does not run. Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, MATE current. A reply requested my desktop launcher file contents; these are pasted below (although a paste has resulted in a truncated line that should read
Exec=/home/ykarant/wandora/wandora-20171012/bin/Wandora.sh )  :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Icon=/home/ykarant/icons-mine/wandora.ico
Icon[en_US]=/home/ykarant/icons-mine/wandora.ico
Name[en_US]=Wandora
Exec=/home/ykarant/wandora/wandora-20171012/bin/Wandora.sh
Name=Wandora
```

output for the other questions:

~/Desktop$ ls -la Wandora.desktop
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ykarant ykarant 242 Nov 10 16:51 Wandora.desktop

What else needs to be configured so that the Launcher Run in Terminal will behave the same as Caja Application in terminal? Note that all of the other desktop execution configuration files -- that do function -- are in Desktop in my home director. Is there an apt install or Snaps application that has the same (or better) functionality than Wandora?

Comment: Does this help: https://askubuntu.com/a/71938

Comment: No -- but the behavior has not changed.  Caja will allow the wandora.sh file [ already chmod a+x for the file, and modified it with DIR="$ (cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)" so that the file can find the other files in the same directory ] to execute and the Wandora GUI appears (eventually), invoking the file from a MATE terminal works, but the desktop launcher does not.  An open terminal appears very briefly on the desktop, closes, but no Wandora.  Is there an error log thereby created that one may examine?

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the contents of your `.desktop` file?  Is it in `usr/share/applications`?  Is it executable?

Comment: @Nmath I have mo dified my comment to include the information you wanted, as you suggested.  Any further suggestions for a work around?

Comment: What happens if you change `Terminal=true` to `Terminal=false`?  Are you sure all of the paths are correct?  Why is the application in your home folder?  Are you sure the script is executable?

Comment: @Nmath  I have installed sunflower, a file manager.  When I select wandora.sh in sunflower, the file executes and presents the Wandora GUI interface, but sunflower also has a terminal screen visible "showing" what was being executed. Is there a mechanism to show you the output?  A literal paste is too long by 1258 characters

Comment: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/

Comment: @Nmath  pastebin done -- through the link you provided.  I also took a screenshot enabling one to see the "entire" desktop GUI with Wandora active and Sunflower behind it.  If you want this,  how I provide a PNG file?